# On Android emulator (hw too?) an Activity style with backgroundDimEnabled also dims GLSurfaceView output

Tags: android

It seems that the emulator is treating GLSurfaceView renderered output
the same as the background wallpaper when the backgroundDimEnabled
style option is set, dimming them both when it should, if I understand
correctly, only dim the wallpaper.

I have a RelativeLayout, whose first child extends GLSurfaceView, that
gets expanded in an Activity with the following style:

```
   <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```

I used to omit the backgroundDimEnabled and set the opengl background
clear color to 0x8000 to dim the wallpaper background, which works
well, but I didn't like the hard edge between the faded activity and
the unfaded wallpaper I would see when the activity slides into and
out of view.

The problem is that when I set the opengl clear color to all 0 and add
the "android:backgroundDimEnabled" the foreground native ui elements
are displayed correctly but the opengl output is dimmed along with the
wallpaper.  If I go back and change backgroundDimEnabled to false or
remove it, the opengl output is at full brightness, but if I ever turn
it back on, rendered output is dimmed.  The only difference is that
style property.

I'm hoping someone knows if this behavior is specific to the emulator,
every version from 2.1-3.0.

I haven't tried yet on physical hardware, maybe someone has an idea?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your issue could be solved by the solution presented here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/0OAFIb2ww2I

The developer in that post called:

```
setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

on his GL surface view.

I had the same issue as you, a surface view being "dimmed out", and his solution worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! I had an issue with ExoPlayer being dimmed, and it was due to it using surface view. This fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the problem exists on an HTC Desire running CM7 (Android 2.3). I've starred your bug report, but it seems that there is only three people in the world with this problem :/

You've probably moved on anyways, but let this be a warning to others before they look for bugs in their own code.