# android:backgroundDimEnabled makes ExoPlayer video go dim/darker

Tags: android, android-view, surfaceview, exoplayer

I'm using [`ExoPlayer2`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) and I've noticed that when I use a theme with [`android:backgroundDimEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#backgroundDimEnabled) set to `true`, the video becomes dark/dimmed as if an overlay is on it. This doesn't happen to `VideoView` or `ImageView` however, only `ExoPlayer`. I don't know enough about `ExoPlayer`, `SurfaceView`, or `android:backgroundDimEnabled`, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

From my understanding, the background dim should only apply to to background, and shouldn't be effecting the views. But if anyone knows a workaround, it would be greatly appreciated.

The style causing this is:

```
<style name="TransparentFloatingActivity" parent="MyAppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <!--<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>-->
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
```

I've confirmed that background dim is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, thanks to [On Android emulator (hw too?) an Activity style with backgroundDimEnabled also dims GLSurfaceView output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161411/on-android-emulator-hw-too-an-activity-style-with-backgrounddimenabled-also-d)

The issue is due to how `SurfaceView` is rendered, so setting the z order to top fixes this:

```
(simpleExoPlayerView?.videoSurfaceView as SurfaceView)?.setZOrderOnTop(true)
```

Comment: if controller_layout_id is set, setZOrderOnTop makes the controller layout invisible

Answer (score 1):

you can add this to attribute

```
app:surface_type="texture_view"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set "backgroundDimEnabled" to false;